# Cutsom Checkbox field in woocommerce product data metabox

Tags: woocommerce

I have added a checkbox to a Woocommerce product page. When I check the box and save it, the box does have the check mark in it and adds "yes" to the field. However, when I try to un-check the checkbox it does not remove the check mark and the field stay as "yes". In some cases the reverse happens, I can get the check mark to be removed but when I try to check the checkbox again it won't check. It doesn't appear to update.

```
  
function wdc_add_checkbox_to_products() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    $term = 'cheque'; // Product category term slug
               
    if ( (has_term( $term, 'product_cat' ) )){   
        woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array( 
        'id' => 'wdc_checkbox',
        'label' => 'Include in List',
        'wrapper_class' => ''
    ) );
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="wdc_checkbox_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce() . '">';  
   
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post_product', 'wdc_save_checkbox_textbox_to_post_meta', 20, 1 );
  
function wdc_save_checkbox_textbox_to_post_meta( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'wdc_checkbox_nonce' ] ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'wdc_checkbox_nonce' ] ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_product', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['wdc_checkbox'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wdc_checkbox', $_POST['wdc_checkbox'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and not testable… Please add the complete testable code editing your question. Remember that *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem"***.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Changed the save function.

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'wdc_save_checkbox_textbox_to_post_meta', 20, 1 );
  
function wdc_save_checkbox_textbox_to_post_meta( $post_id ) {
        $woocommerce_wp_checkbox = isset( $_POST['wdc_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wdc_checkbox', $woocommerce_wp_checkbox );

}
```